# TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined while running jasmine test using karma

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am getting an error while running the following angular test while using jasmine and karma. What I suspect is the call to the 
getCurrencyCodes method in the strip-order component. It calls the tradeservice getCurrencyCodes method which returns an observable.
Is the mock that i have done wrong ?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
```

StripOrdercomponent html

```
 ngOnInit() {
        this.getCurrencyCodes();
    }

  private getCurrencyCodes() {
        this.tradeService.getCurrencyCodes()
            .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.currencyList = data;
            },
            error => {
                this.messageViewerModel.messages.push("Unable to get Currency codes");
            });
    }
```

Strip order spec file

```
class MockDateService {

}


class MockTradeService {
    getCurrencyCodes() {
        return;
    }
}

class MockAuthService {

}

class MockOrderService {

}

class MockValueDateService {

}

class MockClientService {

}


class MockMessageViewerModel {
    title: string;
    messages: string[];
   }

  @Component({
    selector: 'app-message-viewer',
    template: ''
  })
  class MockMessageViewerComponent {
    @Input()
    messageViewer: MockMessageViewerModel;    
  }

describe('StripOrderComponent', () => {
    let component: StripOrderComponent;
    let clientService: ClientService;
    let tradeService: TradeService;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<StripOrderComponent>;


    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                HttpClientModule,
                RouterTestingModule,
                FormsModule,
                TranslateModule.forRoot({
                    loader: {
                        provide: TranslateLoader,
                        useClass: TranslateLanguageLoader
                    }
                })
            ],
            declarations: [
                StripOrderComponent,
                MockMessageViewerComponent,

            ],
            providers: [
                [{ provide: DateService, useClass: MockDateService }],
                [{ provide: TradeService, useClass: MockTradeService }],
                [{ provide: AuthService, useClass: MockAuthService }],
                [{ provide: OrderService, useClass: MockOrderService }],
                [{ provide: ValueDateService, useClass: MockValueDateService }],
                [{ provide: ClientService, useClass: MockClientService }]


            ],
            schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]

        })
            .compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(StripOrderComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();


    });

    it('should be created', () => {
       // spyOn(MockTradeService, 'getCurrencyCodes').and.returnValue({ subscribe: () => {} })
        expect(component).toBeTruthy();
    });


});
```

Comment: because your ` getCurrencyCodes()` returns `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

getCurrencyCodes has to return Observable so that you can subscribe to it. So you need to return Observable (in your mock or spyOn). Few examples:

```
class MockTradeService {
    getCurrencyCodes(): Observable<number> {
        return from([1, 4, 5]);
    }
}
```

You can use different Creators such as of, from, interval, range...
If you want mock function to be executed, then in your spyOn you have to add callThrough

```
spyOn(MockTradeService, 'getCurrencyCodes').and.callThrough();
```

If you want to return another value, then specify:

```
spyOn(MockTradeService, 'getCurrencyCodes').and.returnValue(from([9, 11, 7]));
```